# How can I get the limit of a function of two variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

***Update***:

---

As far as the question is concerned, this limit feature seems to be available only in the version 11.2 and above, as mentioned by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) in his comment below.

---

Somehow I can not get the limit of $\lim_{\{x,y\}\to\{0,0\}}\frac {x^{2}-x y} {\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}$

I tried:

```
Limit[(x^2-x y)/(Sqrt[x]-Sqrt[y]),{x,y}->{0,0}]
```

But I get only the error:

> General: {x, y} is not a valid variable.

I could not find a single example of the limit of a function of two variables in Mathematica. I found [this one](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-calculus/compute-limits-of-multivariate-functions.html?product=mathematica) but I could not get any example of it working.

Comment: `Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]` Make sure you're in _v11.2_ or higher.

Comment: I have only v11.0. Is that the reason? Thanks.

Comment: That's one reason. Notice you've also made several simple mistakes. Just compare your code with mine.

Comment: Thanks, I made the space between x and y in Mathematica. If thats what you meant.

Comment: And `Sqrt(…)` should be `Sqrt[…]`.

Comment: I am using symbol of root from math palette. This was just a typo here.

Comment: You can directly copy&paste the code here to avoid such typo. If you're worried about formatting, have a look at this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871

Comment: In MMA 12.1 on Windows 10 this gives the limit: 0

Comment: I concur, this is the case indeed. Question is irrelevant in this stage. Thanks @DanielHuber.

Comment: Thanks @xzczd for the effort. Well appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned above, this feature is added in _v11.2_: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11.2/ref/Limit.html

Answer (score -2):

Math is very demanding in some situation. Analysis has standards. So it is not sufficient to show:

```
Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

(* 0 *)

You too have to show that

```
Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {y, x} -> {0, 0}]
```

(* 0 *)

and

```
Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]==Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {y, x} -> {0, 0}]
```

(* True *)

The proof is as follows:

(a) Show that the limit exists in the two-step process implemented in Mathematica in `Limit`.
(a1) `x->x0` and `y->y0`
(a2) `y->y0` and `x->x0`
(b) In all four steps the limit must exist, either finite or infinite and be the very same.
(c) If one differs during the step the limit is not the limit and even no limit exists.

In this case a graphic is very instructive:

```
Plot3D[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Plot3D]

This confirms the `Limit` analysis.

It too has the message:

[image: message for Plot3D]

The plot is not done for negative {x,y}. Just for both positive.

There is the path x==y on which the denominator is infinite for all {x,x}! This path is shown in White. It does not belong to the surface.

Since the degree of the polynomial in x and y is higher than 1/2, at least one there is no jump, and a steady extension for the path `x==y` exists.

Examples are `y==0: x^3/2.`

```
x==0: 0.
     

x==y: ((x+eps)^2-x^2)/(Sqrt[x+eps]-Sqrt[x])->(2eps x+eps^2)/(eps/Sqrt[x])->x^3/2+eps Sqrt[x] for eps->0 for x unequal 0.
```

For example : `Series[(Sqrt[x + eps] - Sqrt[x]), {eps, 0, 2}]`

The expansion around the path `x==y` is the main reason for th result.

For cases like this were the limit exist and is finite and zero there can no counterexample be given. The other cases are better solved by a counterexample.

Since Mathematica works in the `Complexes` this example is different, because Mathematica works in the `Reals`. Try the Plot3D with the borders {{0,1},{0,1}} and look for the difference.

```
Plot3D[ReIm[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y])], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Plot3D ReIm]

```
Plot3D[Re[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y])], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Plot3D real part]

So the real part has a line y==0 where the visualisation has bigger problems. These problems are smaller the smaller x is in the `Complexes`.

Comment: The main reason of the question is to find out if MMA has such capability, and if so how that could be used. Learning the limit itself, or visualizing it, are completely another matter.  The software is used to show or visualize results, not to prove them. It is up to the learner to understand and prove.

Comment: This answer is completely off base because the initial premise is incorrect.If `Limit[(x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]` gives a result, then that result is independent of approach path in the real plane.Check the documentation page for `Limit` and in particular all parts that discuss multivariate limits.

Comment: Have a look at the [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CantorStaircase.html]. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function]. Look up [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function] for right-hand and left-hand sidedness of limits of functions.

Comment: Those references in no way salvage this answer. It is simply not pertinent to the question of computing a multivariate limit in n-dimensional real space.